# No token from CommonTokenStream use Antlr

Tags: antlr, grammar

I am a newbie for Antlr. I write a little grammar for practice but get confused by the API CommonTokenStream

```
lexer grammar Expr;
options {
  language = Java;
}

EXPRS:EXPRT {System.out.println($EXPRT.text);};
fragment
EXPRT : 'xxx' ID {System.out.println($ID.text);} ' zzz';
fragment 
ID : ('a'..'z' |'A'..'Z' |'_' )('a'..'z' |'A'..'Z'|'_')*;
```

The Test code is like that:

```
ANTLRStringStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(msg);
Expr expr = new Expr(input);
CommonTokenStream cs = new CommonTokenStream(expr);
System.out.println(cs.size());
```

Whatever the input is, there is no token from the CommonTokenStream.
However, it will ouput when I use expr directly.
Anyone knows why?
The version of antlr is 3.5

Answer (score 3):

`CommonTokenStream` is lazily initialized. To force it to immediately populate all tokens (by calling `nextToken` on your lexer until EOF is reached), you can call the `fill()` method:

```
CommonTokenStream cs = new CommonTokenStream(expr);
cs.fill();
System.out.println(cs.size());
```

Comment: thank you very much. It works. it took me 2 days on the question. All the sample I found on the internet doesn't mention it. I visit the official website, only found a java doc. Do you know any material of the API introduction of antlr?

Comment: @user2202494 you should mark this answer as the "correct answer". It also helped me solve my problem, and it was not obvious from any docs.